# Split and explore a column of dictionaries into separate columns with Pandas

Tags: dataframe, api, multiple-columns

I have a data get from API website. I am using Python 3.9 and try to split the measurements parameter to separate columns, but this column has a dictionary.
I want to get keys of dictionary to a new columns to visualize data.
[Frame with measurements column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCiEw.png)
I need to split this column into separate columns, so that the DataFrame looks like this:
[Frame with measurement columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG4Fu.png)

And below is my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://api.openaq.org/v2/latest?`your text`limit=1000&page=1&offset=0&sort=desc&radius=1000&order_by=lastUpdated&dumpRaw=false'

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.content) 
data  = json.loads(response.text)
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data['results'])`
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please follow prompts like *Enter image description*. If you want images embedded, add a `!` before the square brackets.

Comment: I find stack**overflow** / StackExchange to work best with an explicit question: What is yours here?